Custom metrics using micrometer's @Timed annotation getting removed sometime
Gradle dependency - implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
import io.micrometer.core.annotation.Timed;

@Override
@Timed(value = "custom.mrl.produce", description = "Metrics for JMS producer to RDB")
public void notify(Object message) {

// something here

}

The problem I am facing is that sometimes this custom metrics is not showing up in my /actuator/metrics endpoint.
I tried going through the documentation but didn't found anything related to this issue.

io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave does not contain @Timed, it is from io.micrometer:micrometer-core.
The /actuator/metrics endpoint is for troubleshooting metrics purposes, please do not scrape it in production. If your application restarts meters will not show up in the metrics endpoint unless they were recorded; in your case: unless the method that @Timed is on is called.
